# .Net Core 2.0 Razor Page handle button click data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

With Razor Pages what is the best way to handle this situation where I'd like to have a user click a button within a table and then have a task which uses elements passed from the row for an action?

So far I have this table loaded with a data model and I'd like them to click a row and use that row in my action:

Data Model:

```
   public struct CollapseReportModel
{
    public HighLevelOutput Summary { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<HighLevelOutput> WeeksOfData { get; set; }
}
```

Table:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="accordion">
        @{int counter = 0; }
        @foreach (var dataVM in Model.CollapseReport)
        {
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="heading@(counter)">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse@(counter)" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse@(counter)">
                            @dataVM.ToString()

                        </button>
                    </h5>
                </div>

                <div id="collapse@(counter)" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading@(counter)" data-parent="#accordion">
                    <div class="card-body">
```

I'm trying to use this button click to send data to a task but it just passes null values:

```
                        <form method="post">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Add to Log" asp-page-handler="AddLog" asp-route-data="@dataVM.Summary.CorpCustomer, @dataVM.Summary.Item)" />
                        </form>

                        <ul class="list-group">
                            @foreach (var item in dataVM.WeeksOfData)
                            {
                                <li class="list-group-item">@($"{item.Item}, {item.ItemDescription}, {item.CorpCustomer}, {item.SummedOrder}, {item.SummedForecast}, {item.Difference}, {item.Week}")</li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            counter++;
        }
    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

To this handler:

```
    public  Task<IActionResult> OnPostAddLog(string var1, string var2)
    {
        //Use elements from the row to perform an action
        var test = var1;
        var t2 = var2;

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add inputs to your form so they will be posted to your action.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="var1" value="@dataVM.WhateverProperty1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="var2" value="@dataVM.WhateverProperty2" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Add to Log" asp-page-handler="AddLog" asp-route-data="@dataVM.Summary.CorpCustomer, @dataVM.Summary.Item)" />
</form>
```

Be sure to match the input name to the parameter name in your action.

Also, decorate your `OnPostAddLog` method with `[HttpPost]` as your form use POST method.

Comment: that did the trick to pass the value, I am new to web and learning Razor, is what I'm doing here a good practice for passing data?

Comment: I don't have complete insight on your project, it would be hard for me to tell you if you're doing it 'right', but at least it works.
Please read [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) if you want to know basic principles and learn more conventional way of doing.

Comment: Okay thank you, one more question - is it typical for the page to refresh on a post?

Comment: It's up to you. Again, it depends on what you want to achieve. Sometimes you need to post data then go back to the same page with updated data, sometimes you will want to redirect to another page.
There is no typical.